# Expected value inequality

Tags: inequality, expectation, self-learning

For positive random variables $X,Y$ prove that if $E(X/Y)<1$ then $E(\sqrt{X})\le \sqrt{E(Y)}$. I can use Jensen $E(\sqrt{X})\le \sqrt{E(X)} = \sqrt{E((X/Y)Y)}\le \sqrt{E(Y)}$. I am not sure about validity of the last step in my proof. Is this correct or how should I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\sqrt{X}=\sqrt{\frac{X}{Y}}\sqrt{Y}$. Now apply Holder inequality.